# How can I save multiple values to sessionStorage and display them?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I want to have a calculation history on a calculator, but I just can't seem to get it working. I tried using `sessionStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(this.entries));` but all it ever did was rewrite previous values. How can i save multiple values to sessionStorage and display them all?

https://jsfiddle.net/1bjxzamu/1/

Comment: Nice calculator. You can store a JSON array, get it, `push` to it and then set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `previous value` and update with `new value` then save it.

```
const saveData = (newEntry) => {
  let entries = sessionStorage.getItem("entries") || []
  entries.push(newEntry)
  sessionStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(entries))
}
saveData(["test"])
```